# saving information into database using text box and web services

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, silverlight, webmethod

Ok I can use the `SaveScore();` method alone in my button click to save the score to the db in column count, but im also trying to enable the user to enter there name in the text box `inputname.text` and have that insert into Name column on the database as well.

its the `inputname.text` that is not inserting if I only have the `SaveScore();` in button click it works(inserts score into count column)

But inputname.text i can not get that to insert the string in to Name column

**Here is the C# code**

```
 private void SaveScore()
    {
        ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient service = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
        service.SaveScoreCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.SaveScoreCompletedEventArgs>(SaveScoreCompleted);
        service.SaveScoreAsync(PopBalloonCount);
    }

 void SaveScoreCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.SaveScoreCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Error == null)
          if (e.Result == true)
              Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
          //  showsave.Text = "saved succesfully";   
          else
              showsave.Text = " Not saved ";        
   }

  private void savestuff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient serv = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
       serv.SaveScoreCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.
       SaveScoreCompletedEventArgs>(SaveScoreCompleted);
       serv.SaveScoreAsync(Int32.Parse(nameinput.Text)); // need to save nameinput.text string into Name column 
        SaveScore(); // where score in to count column
    }
```

**Web Service and query**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public bool SaveScore(int Score)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Balloon_Math;Integrated Security=True";
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
       // string myQuery = "INSERT INTO score(count, GameDate) VALUES (" + Score + ",'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d", culture) + "')";
        string myQuery = "INSERT INTO score(count, GameDate, Name) VALUES (" + Score + ",'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d", culture) + "','" + Score.ToString() + ")";
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In web method you are inserting score from the input,what value you want to insert to the Name column..?The same input text(Score) you want to insert..?

Comment: the score is being input from a private int that is increased via ++ on a action in the program. I wish to insert the value from nameinput.Text into Name

Comment: The same score value you want to insert with text into the database ("Your Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(score))..?

Comment: the score value is fine and is inserting in to the count column, i wish to insert nameinput.text value into Name column

Comment: what is the value in the nameinput.text ..?Can't you send one more parameter to WebMethod..?

Comment: The value will be input but the user and it will be of string value, it could be Tom or Bob. and im not to confident with web method so im not sure.

Comment: please explain in detail because you are sending nameinput.text to web method serv.SaveScoreAsync(Int32.Parse(nameinput.Text)); and you are inserting it into Score Column.

Comment: Ok, what I am trying to do is insert the value from inputname.text into Name column, and Score(); into count column. Score(); is inserting into count column but I need the inputname.text value to insert into Name column.